# Jersey @Path mapping queries

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jackson

I have a following jersey class .

```
@Path("/static1/static2")
public class DoStuff {

@POST
@Path("/static3")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
@Produces("application/xml")
public Response validation(String inputXML){
```

so my url is `localhost/static1/static2/static3` and I get a `200`

my goal is to have a URL that is

```
localhost/static1/{variable}/static2/static3
```

I tried modifying my class in the following way

```
@Path("/static1/{variable}/static2")
    public class DoStuff {

    @POST
    @Path("/static3")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    @Produces("application/xml")
    public Response validation(String inputXML){
```

but I keep getting a `404` , what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: I solved the {variable} problem by adding a path param but I cannot solve the format problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be with the last path segment `static3.{format}`. Try the following:

```
@Path("/static1/{variable}/static2")
    public class DoStuff {

    @POST
    @Path("/{segment3:static3.*}")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    @Produces("application/xml")
    public Response validation(@PathParam("variable") String variable,
                               @PathParam("segment3") String segment3, 
                               String inputXML) {
       ...............
    }
```

Comment: @Anrei , yes your answer did solve the question . if you could also explain why this solves the problem , it will be awesome.

Comment: A path segment contains by default all characters except `/`. When you wrote `static3/{segment3}.suffix/` it was not clear for Jersey (probably a bug or simply it is not a MUST to have implemented it according to the JAX-RS spec) that segment3 + suffix should be a segment.